# how to hide foreach wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, hide

i want to hide foreach wrong.
For example error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\AppServ\www\ebook\ara.php on line 65
```

how i can hide?

Comment: You do not want to hide it. You want to fix it.

Comment: this is one of the question a developers should never do

Comment: @BoltClock: Can't +1 that more.

Comment: Can we see some of the code (especially the `foreach` loop) that generated this error?

Comment: Don't try to "hide" errors. Work out what's causing them, then fix it. In this case, it seems that you're supplying an invalid argument to `foreach`.  Since `foreach` only takes arrays as input, I presume that you are passing something other than an array. Look at the code where the error occurs (the line and file indicated in your question) and work it out. If you can't, edit your question to provide the code that causes the error.

Comment: @adarshr: Your comment makes the fact that I received 10 comment upvotes **in a single minute** seem ever the creepier.

Comment: @all sorry My first language is no English..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that foreach() has count

```
if (count($array))
{
   foreach($array as $value)
   {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: Even if `$array` is empty, as long as it's actually an array `foreach` won't emit the warning.

Comment: @BoltClock: correct, but `foreach` would do nothing on an empty array anyway so this works. Although personally I would declare `$array` as an array first, or make sure any function that assigns it returns an array.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: "so this is unnecessary". Plus it's a solution to the wrong problem.

Answer (score 6):

Never hide errors. Errors mean that there is something wrong, you should try to fix the underlying problem rather than hide it

Also, we need to see some code so we know what you're passing to the foreach. It much be an array

Comment: Whatever, same thing to me. It's something that shouldn't happen.

Comment: I agree when your application is under development, seeing errors will really aid you, but when an application is in production turning off error reporting is usually a good idea. Besides no errors or warnings will appear when your app is ready to go production right? :)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways:

1) Check the variable first

```
  if(isset($rows) && is_array($rows))
  {
      foreach($rows as $row) { ... }
  }
```

2) Use the error suppression operator (don't do this please...)

```
  foreach(@$rows as $row) { ... }\
```

3) Turn off all errors (better not do this or you will be sorry!)

```
  error_reporting(E_NONE);
```

Comment: I doubt `isset` and `is_array` is the solution. The code above should probably be modified so that it can't be anything other than an array.

Comment: @lonseomeday Well it depends on how he is getting the array variable. Somtimes you get them as the result of other calls, and cant be sure what it is. I.e. if you have a function that returns null, or an array you have to check.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the variable you pass to it is an array/exists.

Please post some code and we can help you further.

And as other's are saying here, you don't want to hide errors.. They'll cause your script to break, it's bad practice and it get's you nowhere.

You can however supress errors by putting an @ symbol before the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can set error reporting to false in your php.ini but this is not recommended. It looks like you should fix the error before trying to figure out how to hide it.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

[PHP Error Reporting](http://php.net/error_reporting)

Answer (score 2):

As BoltClock said, you should definitely fix this problem.  If you don't, it could lead you to serious trouble later.

The following are a couple of ways to hide errors.  I put them here for educational purposes... you shouldn't use them without good reason (and that is almost never!).

You can put `@` in front of a function.

You can change [`display_errors`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

You can change [`error_reporting`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting).

Answer (score 1):

```
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place an @ symbol in front of the line of code that is causing the error. The @ symbol causes PHP to suppress errors that occur on the line. This is not usually recommended unless you have a good reason for it. It is better to fix errors.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the @ symbol for a foreach

> PHP Manual: *foreach* does not support the ability to suppress error messages using '@'.